# How safe and practical is torrenting?

Tags: malware, torrent

From my understanding, torrenting differs from standard downloading because it will get pieces of the file from other torrent clients, making it faster (and decentralized if I'm not wrong).

How safe is this? Could a user of a torrent client do something malicious with their piece of the file? I just want to download Linux ISOs faster.

Could I end up getting malware?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Yes, you could end up downloading malware if you download stuff without using your brain.

Comment: ISP grumpiness is not a security concern. And you would need to ask your ISP. That part of the question has been removed.

Comment: Torrenting is a perfectly valid and useful protocol. Torrenting Linux distributions is common and practical. Like any form of download, it's recommended that you check the result against a signature if available. Some ISPs choose not to support the protocol due to a high volume of misuse.

Comment: The title of the duplicate says "fake" but the answer deals with all types of malicious uses.